# Custom Mouse Cursor for Tkinter on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, mouse, tk-toolkit

I am trying to make a game using tkinter that will have it's own special mouse. I have seen a lot of desktop games that use this and have seen related questions but don't know how to do it for windows and python 3. I tried to do `root['cursor']="@mouse.cur"` but I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python32/game.py", line 4, in <module>
    root["cursor"]="@mouse.cur"
  File "C:\Python32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1200, in __setitem__
    self.configure({key: value})
  File "C:\Python32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1193, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1184, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: bad cursor spec "@mouse.cur"
```

I have a file in the same directory called `mouse.cur` and has correct dimensions (32x32) and is not corrupt. Could someone tell me if I am supposed to put it into some sort of subfolder of do it some other way. Thanks in advance.
Windows 10, Python 3.2.2

Comment: When you say it's in the same directory, is it the same directory as the script, or your current working directory?

Comment: @BryanOakley both

Comment: @BryanOakley do you have any sort of answer, I really would like one

Comment: Can you post the code also?

Comment: You're missing the last quote mark at the end of the error...

Comment: Hmm.. Works for me windows 7, python 3.1.1. Are you sure it's not a `.ani` cursor file or anything else?

Comment: @ArtemisFowl This is windows 10, python 3.2

Comment: I know. What about the other thing I asked.

Comment: @ArtemisFowl it is called mouse.cur

Comment: Why dont you use pygame then? Tkinter isnt made for games with how its structured.

Comment: @Pygasm because this is useful for things other than games

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm unable to reproduce your problem on any Win system that I have. However, despite the vague error `_tkinter.TclError: bad cursor spec "@mouse.cur"`, you're still able to hunt down your problem.

The "bad cursor spec" error occures inside of the [`TkGetCursorByName`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/tcl/tcl-102/tk84/tk/win/tkWinCursor.c.auto.html) function:

```
...
if (argv[0][0] == '@') {

    ...

    cursorPtr->winCursor = LoadCursorFromFile(&(argv[0][1]));
} else {

    ...

}

if (cursorPtr->winCursor == NULL) {
    ckfree((char *) cursorPtr);
    badCursorSpec:
    ckfree((char *) argv);
    Tcl_AppendResult(interp, "bad cursor spec \"", string, "\"",
        (char *) NULL);
    return NULL;
} else {
    ckfree((char *) argv);
    return (TkCursor *) cursorPtr;
}
...
```

As you can see, problem stems from the [`LoadCursorFromFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648392(v=vs.85).aspx), which is a standard WinAPI function for such case.

I assume, that `LoadCursorFromFile(&(argv[0][1]));` yields a `Null` result, therefore `cursorPtr->winCursor == NULL` evaluates to `True`, hence the error.

However, we can call this function outside the `tkinter` and check the error:

```
import ctypes

get_error = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetLastError
load_cursor = ctypes.windll.user32.LoadCursorFromFileW

cur_handle = load_cursor('mouse.cur')
err = get_error()

print('cursor handle:\t%s, '
      'err no:\t%d, '
      'err desc:\t%s' % (cur_handle, err, ctypes.FormatError(err)))
```

- `cur_handle` is not `0` (`Null`), `err` is `0` - not our case
- `cur_handle` is `0` (`Null`), `err` is `2` - double check names and paths
- `cur_handle` is `0` (`Null`), `err` is `0` - probably a GDI/User object leak (an exhaustion of handles)
- `cur_handle` is `0` (`Null`), `err` is `8` - definitely a GDI/User object leak

Comment: How would I fix this? err is 0

Comment: @Hippolippo, if `cur_handle` is not 0, then I could suggest you to update your question with the [tag:tk] tag and `tk`/`tcl` versions. Otherwise (if `cur_handle` is also 0) look for a leakage in your system.

Comment: @Hippolippo, I'm curious, is it a third case (a GDI leak) or a second case (a non-zero cursor handle) ?

Comment: `cur_handle` is `0`, `err` is `0`. You say that I should look for a leak, how would I do this and when I find it, how would I fix it?

Comment: @Hippolippo, It's not necessarily a resource leakage or an exhaustion of handles, however it's a most logical cause. Clearly, the problem is not in the `tkinter`, but somewhere outside in the system. The GDI/User object count can be checked via Task Manager on the [processes tab](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/83543-task-manager-add-remove-columns.html). Since a cursor is one of the [User objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725486(v=vs.85).aspx), the user object count is more interesting to you. If that the case: obviously reduce usage or increase limits.

Comment: I gave you the bounty since it expired today but this is not solved yet. I will check what you said when i get home

Comment: There is no process called user

Comment: @Hippolippo, [It's not a process, but a column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBBdn.png).

Comment: How do get the user object count, there is only one user in the list, and how do I increase limits

Comment: I did some testing and I have come to the conclusion that my cursor file was bad, thanks for the help

Answer (score -1):

Try using

```
root.config(cursor="crosshair")
```

Also, the following link may give you the different types of cursors available: 
http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/cursors.html

Let me know if this also, doesn't work. Happy to help.

Comment: I know how to do that